# Invocation of form tabs.connect(undefined, object) doesn't match definition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I'm making a simple chrome extension and need to have my `popup` page connect to the `content` script on the current tab. However it keeps giving me an error for the `tabId` argument to `tabs.connect`. It's saying the tab id I'm passing is undefined rather than an integer. I have no idea why.

Full Error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invocation of form tabs.connect(undefined, object) doesn't match definition tabs.connect(integer tabId, optional object connectInfo)
    at Object.normalizeArgumentsAndValidate (extensions::schemaUtils:115)
    at Object.<anonymous> (extensions::binding:363)
    at connectToCurrentTab (popup.js:21)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (popup.js:44)
    at mightThrow (jquery-3.2.1.js:3583)
    at process (jquery-3.2.1.js:3651)
```

I made a short `function` to retrieve the current tab id:

```
function getCurrentTabId() {
    var query = {active: true, currentWindow: true};

    var tabId;

    chrome.tabs.query(query, function (tabArray) {
        tabId = tabArray[0].id;

        console.log("Tab id: " + tabId);
    });

    return tabId;
}
```

It appears to be getting the correct tab id or at least an integer. Console out put: `Tab id: 111`

I use the current tab id retrieved by `getCurrentTabId` to `chrome.tabs.connect` from my `popup` to the `content` script running on the current tab then return the `Port` it connected on.

```
function connectToCurrentTab () {
    var currentTabId = getCurrentTabId();

    return chrome.tabs.connect(currentTabId, {name: "popup"}); //<-- error thrown here
}
```

Any help or information is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, the problem it's than `chrome.tabs.query` is async method. So, at the moment when you call `chrome.tabs.connect` - `currentTabId` it's `undefined`.

You can fix it with usage of `callback` function:

```
function getCurrentTabId(cb) {
    var query = {active: true, currentWindow: true};
    chrome.tabs.query(query, function (tabArray) {
        console.log("Tab id: " + tabArray[0].id);
        cb(tabArray[0].id)
    });
}

function connectToCurrentTab () {
    getCurrentTabId(function(currentTabId) {
       chrome.tabs.connect(currentTabId, {name: "popup"})
    });
}
```

You can also use a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to prevent a callbacks hell.

Comment: Fixed my problem. Much appreciated sir! Must have missed the part about it being asynchronous in the documentation. Been programming ever since I can remember and still making rookie mistakes. :P Oh well, happens to all of us.