# Obtain the tabId of new created tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How do I get the tabId of a new created tab? My tabId I want to send in sendMessage is undefinded.
How do I get the tabId?

Later I need the tabId to update the tabs....

popup.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('button').on('click', function () {
      chrome.tabs.create({
          url: "http://google.de"
      }, function(tab) {
        });
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({content: tabId, type:'urlDe'});
        window.close();
    });
      chrome.tabs.create({
          url: "http://google.com"
      }, function(tab) {
        });
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({content: tabId, type:'urlCom'});
        window.close();
    });
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
    if (request.type === 'urlDe') {
        alert(request.type + request.content);
    } else if (request.type === 'urlCom') {
        alert(request.type + request.content);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access to the `tabId` via `tab.id` in your callback function, because `chrome.tabs.create` is async function:

```
 chrome.tabs.create({
      url: "http://google.de"
  }, function(tab) {
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage({content: tab.id, type:'urlDe'});
  });
});
```

More information are in [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) or in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089389/invocation-of-form-tabs-connectundefined-object-doesnt-match-definition/48089478#48089478).

Comment: Thanks, but the code in function(tab) {
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage({content: tab.id, type:'urlDe'});
  }); never gets executed. If I put it outside the callback it will be executed, why?

Comment: I think its why its in a popup, and when the new window gets opened, the code stops